# Consulta SQL Server según condición y fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, transact-sql

Hola por favor me ayudan con el siguiente resultado esperado en SQL Server:

Tabla Marcas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Mantenciones :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla deseada :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo obtener según una marca su mantención mas próxima a su fecha de ingreso.

Agradeceré algún ejemplo o guía respecto a esto, gracias.

```
create table #marcas (id int, marca nvarchar(40), fecha_ingreso date)
create table #mantenciones (id int, marca nvarchar(40), fecha_mantencion date)
insert into #marcas values (1,'FIAT','2020-03-10'),(2,'FORD','2020-04-05'),(3,'MAZDA','2020-05-01');
insert into #mantenciones values (1,'FIAT','2020-03-15'),(2,'FIAT','2020-03-17'),(3,'FIAT','2020-03-20');
insert into #mantenciones values (4,'FORD','2020-04-20'),(5,'FORD','2020-04-07');
insert into #mantenciones values (6,'MAZDA','2020-05-01'),(7,'MAZDA','2020-05-02');

SELECT * FROM #marcas;
SELECT * FROM #mantenciones
SELECT m.id,m.marca,ma.id,ma.fecha_mantencion FROM #marcas m

CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM #mantenciones
         WHERE Marca = m.Marca
         AND fecha_mantencion >= m.fecha_ingreso
         ORDER BY fecha_mantencion) ma;

DROP TABLE #mantenciones
DROP TABLE #marcas
```

Comment: Igual y me equivoco pero me parece un error de diseño y que puede repercutir el hecho de que estás repitiendo los nombres de las marcas en ambas tablas

Comment: Posiblemente te haga falta un campo que ayude a reconocer los vehículos, p.ej. Matrícula y como señaló @BetaM tienes problemas de diseño, más aún cuando no puedes decir cuando coinciden marcas en dos tablas cómo se corresponden de una a otra. La base de datos no puede ver lo que ven los mecánicos.

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server estas usando?

Comment: @BetaM,  efectivamente debe ir el ID Marca en la tabla de mantenciones lo hice así solo para que se entendiera el script.

Comment: @quevedo solo para el script lo interprete así, lo importante es saber o entender la logica de como obtener según una marca su mantención mas próxima a su fecha de ingreso.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho 2008 SQL Server R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que tu versión ya soporta [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y [`CTE's`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), por lo que podrías plantear algo como esto:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT m.id,
       m.marca,
       ma.id as 'id_mantencion',
       ma.fecha_mantencion,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.marca 
                          ORDER BY datediff(day, m.fecha_ingreso, ma.fecha_mantencion) DESC) as RN
       FROM #marcas m
       LEFT JOIN #mantenciones ma
          on ma.marca = m.marca
 )
 SELECT id,
        marca,
        id_mantencion,
        fecha_mantencion
        FROM cte
        WHERE RN = 1;
```

Básicamente:

- Usamos un [`CTE's`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para hacer más simple la consulta, pero podría utilizarse una subconsulta también, la idea es materializar un enumerador de filas
- Con [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) generamos un numerador por `marca` y en relación al orden dado por la diferencia de días
- Finalmente solo nos quedamos con las filas número 1 que son las que justamente tienen la menor diferencia en días.

Comment: Estimado Patricio muchas gracias, su respuesta ha sido el puente para lograr lo mencionado. Lo adapte a la query original y cambie el cross apply por su codigo y el tiempo se redujo de 2 min a 10 seg.!!!!! Muchas gracias Patricio, que tenga una excelente semana.